# PHP: How do I get a system user's uid for a given user name?

Tags: php

In perl, I have these functions: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpwuid

Is there anything similar in PHP? I want to look up the system uid for a given user name. I googled around and nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: like [that](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php)?

Comment: Yeah, found it about 30 seconds after I posted this question. Thanks, though!

Comment: Close it please :)

Comment: Why, is it a dupe?

Comment: I think it's a bit trivial question, honestly I didn't know this function but simply writing "getpwuid in php" I found it. the real question is, Is this question really needed? :)

Comment: There's huge numbers of trivial questions on here. I didn't see it on google immediately. Took about 5 min. This question might save others from the same problem.

Comment: Perfect i did answer for all so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes exist, that function is call `posix_getpwuid` - [Official Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php)